# Is <?= a valid php statement?

Tags: php, asp-classic, tags, short

Is there a php.ini setting to turn `<?=$phpval?>`-style output on, or has someone on this project been smoking too much ASP?

Comment: "smoking to much ASP?" Golden quote.

Comment: As a side note, you can quickly check php syntax using online editors such as ideone.

Comment: You can also quickly load up the PHP manual in your web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

```
<?php $var = 'Hello, World!"; ?>
<?= $var ?>
```

Is the same as;

```
<?php $var = 'Hello, World!"; ?>
<?php echo $var; ?>
```

Comment: `<?=` is actually short for `<?php echo`, not `<?php print`. echo is not the same as print, as it allows multiple strings to be outputted at once, whereas print only allows one.

Answer (score 2):

There is, but it is deprecated.
You are looking for `short_open_tag` which enables `<?` (DANGER because of xml opening tags that are the same) and `<?=` (no danger)

As of php 5.4, `<?=` will be enabled even if `short_open_tag` is set to Off.
See [the documentation](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

Comment: Note that `<?=` is always allowed in PHP 5.4, whether `short_open_tag` is on or not.

Comment: @duskwuff: that's what I tried to say, but not putting the `<?=` between ` messed up my answer.

Comment: Note also that in php 3.3.8 (And probably earlier versions as well) it turns on/off with the short_open_tag php.ini directive.Also, if you change that setting in your ini file, restart apache and still nothing happens, make sure your using the correct ini file as shown in phpinfo(); Derp.

Comment: What?! Why are they doing that?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : What do you mean, "that"?

Comment: @greg0ire: The thing that your answer and the first comment talks about.

Comment: They are doing that so that people can use `<?=` safely, that is, whithout having `<?` recognized as a php opening tag.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Its a valid statement, and as @greg0ire mentioned you can turn it on by editing the `short_open_tag` in php.ini however using `<?php` has been known as a better practice specially if you are writing your application for sale to the public, because `<?php` would work with most shared hosting configurations however `<?` is sometimes not allowed/not activated, so its easier for users to use your script if you use `<?php`.